# Присоединение или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Я не видела его сегодня(,) и вчера тоже.

Мне не нравится, когда меня разглядывают(,) и фотографируют тоже.

Нужны ли запятые? Хочется поставить, но я сомневаюсь.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я не видела его сегодня, и вчера тоже. Мне не нравится, когда меня разглядывают, и фотографируют тоже.

И ТОЖЕ — присоединительный составной союз (присоединительный союз И + наречие ТОЖЕ).

**ТОЖЕ**. I. нареч. Равным образом, в равной мере; также. Он устал, я т. Одежда грязная, обувь т. Я перестал спрашивать, все т. приумолкли.

ПАС: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

**Присоединительные члены предложения** имеют характер сведений добавочных, сообщаемых попутно, в дополнение к содержанию основного высказывания. Такие члены предложения **выделяются запятыми** и обычно вводятся словами и сочетаниями слов (**частицами, союзами или их сочетанием**) даже, в особенности, особенно, главным  образом, в том числе, в частности, например, и притом, и потому, да и, да и только, да и вообще, и, тоже, **и тоже**, причем и др.

Answer (score 2):

Замечу, что в литературе встречается без запятой:

> Я ничего не пил сегодня и вчера тоже. (В.И. Немирович-Данченко)
>
> У нас сегодня Маслобоев был и вчера тоже был... (Ф.М. Достоевский)
>
> Сегодня пробовал писать и вчера тоже... (Игорь Кузьмичев)
>
> Боюсь, я сегодня немного перепил и вчера тоже... (Грегори Дэвид Робертс)

(С запятой при поиске тоже один раз попалось.)

Второе предложение я бы построил иначе:

**Мне не нравится, когда меня разглядывают, и когда фотографируют — тоже.**