# Помогите разобрать предложение

Tags: запятые, сказуемые, подлежащее, интонация, инфинитив

Переложение: "Убирать нужно было брата своего, и Шарипова этого тоже".

Вопросы:

1. Какая грамматическая основа (или несколько)?
2. Нужная ли запятая? А если для интонации?
3. Если запятая не нужна / необязательна, то как читатель поймёт, что Шарипова убрать, а не брата Шарипова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Убирать нужно было брата своего, **и Шарипова этого тоже**.*

1. Грамматическая основа: **убирать нужно было**. Предложение безличное.

**Сказуемое** составное глагольное: модальная связка "нужно было" + инфинитив "убирать".

2. **Запятая нужна (обязательна)** для выделения присоединительной конструкции, присоединительный союз: И + наречие ТОЖЕ.

Правило: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123
§ 84. Присоединительные члены предложения. (Здесь союз И ТОЖЕ указан как присоединительный.)

В предложении два дополнения (брата, и Шарипова тоже). Грамматически они "однородны" (относятся  к одному сказуемому и имеют форму беспредложного В.п.) но по семантике второе дополнение является присоединительным.

3. **Интонационно** присоединительный оборот выделен паузой.
4. **Похожий вопрос** уже рассматривался:
   [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436269/Присоединение-или-нет](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436269/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)

Там в ответах были указаны оба варианта, так что окончательный выбор может зависеть от структуры предложения. Запятая обычно не ставится в простых случаях вида: *Сегодня пробовал писать и вчера тоже*. Тогда союз И будет считаться соединительным, паузы нет.